# Create a program solution using Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

How can i create a program solution using Matlab for the problem below?

The program will prompt for number of people, which will be input from keyboard, and saves it in a variable called noOfPeople. It will then prompt for the age of each person and saves them in a matrix called ages. The program will also need to check if the ages are between 0-60. If age, if above 60, the program will give an error "invalid, try again..".

Comment: Yes you can, it' very very basic Matlab. Have a look at the [input](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/input.html) to get started

Answer (score -2):

This is a simple program to capture the number of people and their ages.

You should run the following from the command prompt:

> > y = myprogram;

```
function y = myprogram(~)

noOfPeople = input('No of people');

for i = 1:noOfPeople
    age = input('input age between 0-60');
    if (double(age)>60 || double(age<0))
       error('Invalid, try again!');  
    end
    y(i) = age;
end
```

Comment: Every time you enter someone whose age is out of range, you will record their age as zero. You need to replace that `if` with a `while`  and put the `input` inside the new `while` loop

Comment: You must replace that `&&` with `||`. As it stands, the condition can never be met and that part is utterly useless. The program will record anything numerical. Your usage of `numel` also seems wrong...

Comment: @Dan: I used the `if` loop on purpose. It errors mentioning that the age is incorrect as was asked by the author of this question.

Comment: @scenia: I have modified my answer with the suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: @LokeshA.R. will the above work if there are more than 1 people? for example No. of people is 5, it will ask the age of person 1, person 2 person 3, person 4, person 5, etc... and in the end how can i add the command to compute the average age?

Comment: @user3296827: yes it will work for more than 1 person. also, to compute the average age `aver_age = mean(y)`.

Comment: @LokeshA.R. i had tried the above commands you provided but i am getting error. pardon me, but i am new to this. what is the purpose of y=myprogram ? i am getting error on this.